# jQuery .html() show \n \t indentation

Tags: jquery, indentation

I'm starting to use jQuery with VScode + Prettier and the .html() method on a code base gives me a string with the html code including the indentation. Is there any configuration to prevent this from happening?

Or is the only solution to process the string by removing the various characters?

Someone wants to explain me why?

```
<ul>
        <li id="1">
            <span>uno</span>
        </li>
        <li id="2">due</li>
        <li id="3">tre</li>
        <li id="4">quattro</li>
        <li id="5">cinque</li>
    </ul>
```

gives me this on console

```
"\n\t\t\t<li id=\"1\">\n\t\t\t\t<span>uno</span>\n\t\t\t</li>\n\t\t\t<li id=\"2\">due</li>\n\t\t\t<li id=\"3\">tre</li>\n\t\t\t<li id=\"4\">quattro</li>\n\t\t\t<li id=\"5\">cinque</li>\n\t\t"
```

Comment: What is the problem having the `\n` and `\t` in the string? Those are not visible characters in html

Comment: Like @charlietfl mentioned, its not really important. If you still want to remove it, try trim function. myString.trim() should remove all whitespaces and new lines